# Is it possible to serve stale data from Redis by design?

Tags: java, caching, redis

I have a Java application that is responsible for serving up various (sometimes large) json responses to client applications. At the app layer, it uses Redis (AWS ElastiCache) to cache the json with TTLs from 30s to 5min depending on the particular request. Some of the requests a rather long-running (5-15s), reaching out to several external services and returning a large amount of data. If the TTL is 60s, that still means that some users are getting unacceptable response times every minute. Instead of immediately evicting the data from the cache when the TTL is up, I'd like to kick off a background task to fetch the data and refresh the cache, while continuing to serve a stale copy of the data if it exists. Is this possible with Redis?

Comment: Can you set your TTL to longer than the background task interval? then it only expires if something goes wrong.

Comment: Is there a reason that you're using a timeout, instead of invalidating cached items when they change?

Comment: @ChrisTanner - We can't predict which cache keys are going to be requested, so we can't run regularly scheduled background tasks to keep it updated.

Comment: @TagueGriffith - The data we serve up comes from many different sources. Some of them we have the ability to be notified when it changes, and we do set a very long TTL and update the cache only when we get notified. Other sources are more dynamic and we don't have the capability to get notified when it changes, so we have to set a lower TTL (30-60s) that is within the acceptable range for a good user experience.

Answer (score 5):

You can implement this manually by writing a pair of entries for each item you want to cache.

- `item`: the actual item with a TTL set to a hard eviction
- `item/fresh`: Boolean with a TTL set to a soft eviction (i.e mark as stale). This TTL should be less than the hard TTL.

When querying, always ask for both keys

**Scenario 1** - cache miss (`item` does not exist)

- Fetch the item from somewhere
- Populate the cache with both keys
- Return the item

**Scenario 2** - cache hit (both keys exist)

- Return the item

**Scenario 3** - stale (`item/fresh` does not exist)

- Create a job in the background that refreshes both keys
- Return the cached (stale) item

Comment: I know this is an old post, but if we hit scenario 3, and we have a large amount of servers trying to get the value, and calculating the value takes a significant amount of time, it is very likely we will land in a situation were all the servers are running the same expensive background task at the same time, all trying to re-populate the cache.

Separatelly, I believe the same can be achieved by requesting the TTL of the key, and refreshing it if there is less than X time left. This virtually halves the memory footprint and the bandwidth required. (still has the same issue though).

Comment: As I can find surprisingly little info on this, I will just add that the above problem can be solved by having the first server that wants to do the revalidation doing a GETSET with a small expiration time for safety, and only if the value is missing it performs the background update. (just throwing ideas in case anyone else bumbs on this).